# Instance of a number in an array

Tags: ruby, user-input, instanceof

I know "instance_of?" searches for an instance of a class. I am looking for an object that can find an instance of the user input inside the array. Code for clarity:

```
user_input = nil  
array = [[1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6][7, 8, 9]]  

until user_input.instance_of?(array) do  
  print "Choose a number in our array"  
  begin  
    user_input = gets.chomp
  rescue ArgumentError
    user_input = nil
    puts "Not in our array. Try again!"
  end
end
```

Comment: "I know "instance_of?" searches for an instance of a class" - nope, it doesn't search anything. It's a simple check.

Comment: Hi! It looks like you're a bit confused about what `instance_of?` does, Can you clarify the problem a little bit? Is the idea that the user types in a sequence of numbers e.g. `1,2,3` and you want to check if it matches one of the arrays inside your `array` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Array#include?

Here's a simple implementation. I simplified the array for example purposes.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

puts "Enter a number"
while user_input = gets.chomp
  if array.include?(user_input.to_i)
    puts "You got it."
    break
  else
    puts "Not in our array. Try again!"
  end
end
```